# iOS - Physicsbody moving right through another

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

[image]I am making an SpriteKit game involving sorting colored balls with a rotating funnel that rotates based off where you move your touch. Problem is if someone swipes across the screen really fast, balls will move right through the physicsBody on the funnel. I am changing the zRotation of the funnel with each call to touchesMoved(). Both the balls' physicsbody and the funnel's physicsbody has .usesPreciseCollisionDetection to true. .isDynamic is false for the funnel.

I figure when someone swipes across the screen, the animation is happening so fast that the framerate cannot keep up and as the funnel rotates, there is such a large gap in its rotation that the ball ends up on the other side of the physicsbody in a single frame.

Is there any way to fixing this? I am new to SpriteKit, any help is appreciated. My code is [here](https://github.com/momja/Duesquare/blob/master/Duesquare/GameScene.swift)

Comment: use `skView.showsPhysics = true` to find out if your bodies are correct

Comment: Try to use SKAction.rotate instead of change directly zRotation in touchesMoved()

Comment: I tried both of these @Simone I think the problem is with the frame rate. Even using SKAction.rotate, if the angle change is great enough, the funnel moves so fast it skips over spaces in the frame, for example where the ball might be